# Problem with ignoring a directory in git

Tags: git

I've seen many posts on SO about this but none of the solutions I've tried work.

I have a directory structure as follows

```
MySite\Bin
MySite\Obj
MySite\Important
```

My .gitignore file which is at the root is (and yes I've tried removing the * also)

```
MySite\bin\*
MySite\obj\*
```

Executing the command git status shows this

```
#       modified:   .gitignore
#       modified:   SomeOtherFile.fle
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       MySite/bin/
#       MySite/obj/
```

I've tried executing the following commands

```
git rm -r MySite\bin
git rm -r --cached MySite\bin

git rm MySite\bin\fileToIgnore.dll
git rm --cached MySite\bin\fileToIgnore.dll
```

And I keep getting this error
**fatal: pathspec 'MySite/bin' did not match any files**

When executing **git add .** the files in *MySite\Bin* and *MySite\obj* are added to the staging items. Why?

I'm also using the windows version of git (mysysgit).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your slashes in the wrong order.

```
MySite/bin
MySite/obj
```

According to the docs of [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) it is a pattern. And Git path pattern always follows unix path names with forward slashes.

Do that and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. My .gitignore file needed forward slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Not to point out the obvious, but you have Bin and bin. (Note case). I believe git is case sensitive no matter the platform.

Comment: I thought that at first until I saw his untracked files. It isn't a case sensitivity issue, he is using the wrong path delimiter as explained below.